# How to access a directory content when another has been mounted on it?

Tags: mount, partition

There is an existing directory called /home containing some files.
I have mounted a partition on this directory using /etc/fstab

```
UUID=10CD7304CE71E381   /home      ntfs    defaults        0       2
```

Nothing wrong so far.

How do I access the original content of /home without unmounting anything. Obviously, I cannot unmount the mounted /home partition.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, you can do it by unmounting that directory in a separate [mount namespace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mount_namespaces.7.html) with its mount propagation flag set to *private*:

```
# truncate -s 3G blob
# mkfs.ext4 blob
...

# mkdir dir
# echo below > dir/file

# mount blob dir
# echo above > dir/file

# cat dir/file
above

# unshare --mount --fork --propagation private sh -c 'umount dir; cat dir/file'
below

# cat dir/file
above

# unshare --mount --fork --propagation private sh -c '
   umount dir
   for f in dir/file /dev/fd/7; do
       realpath --relative-to=. "$f"; cat "$f"
   done
' 7<dir/file
dir/file
below
dir/file
above
```

Note: the `--propagation private` flag is the default, at least with recent versions of `unshare(1)`: I have added it just for emphasis.

Comment: `man unshare`, not if it is mounted as shared :( `findmnt -o+PROPAGATION`

Answer (score 0):

Using bind mount is simpler. I couldn't make the `unshare` solution to work. It didn't want to umount a busy filesystem.

```
mkdir /mnt/tmproot
mount --bind / /mnt/tmproot
ls /home # Still shows contents of mounted /home partition
ls /mnt/tmproot/home # pre-mount contents of mountpoint /home dir
```

credits to original answer: https://superuser.com/a/977082/111432

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer: use a live system.

If another partition has been mounted on your root's `/home`, indeed you cannot simply unmount it, or even re-bind the mount. However, a live system has it's own /home/ arranged for and doesn't use the partition that normally provides your root filesystem. So on the live system, simply mount your root filesystem and you can access the original /home directory from there.

Finding a live system shouldn't be difficult, because there are quite a few distributions that provide a live CD image that you can burn on CD, or put on a USB drive to boot from there. Some of the distributions that offer this are Debian, Knoppix and MX Linux.

Comment: This provides a solution for the user's specific problem, but fails to answer the general question being asked.